# filedialog.askopenfilename() takes a longer time to execute when executing the entire code the 2nd time

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am allowing a user to select excel files before performing a merge operation. When the code runs for the 1st instance in the jupyter notebook. It runs fine. On the second instance when i run the entire code again the execution of the code takes a longer time. Forcing me to kill the session and re-open a jupyter notebook session again.

I am using Pandas along with tkinter to open and read the file. Below is my code snippet.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

# Selecting the files
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.update()

# Garn Team Data or Data from ADP R
emp_data=pd.read_excel(filedialog.askopenfilename()
                        ,header = 0)

# Pay Team Data
team_data=pd.read_excel(filedialog.askopenfilename()
                           , header = 0)

#Merging the files
data_applied=pd.merge(left=emp_data,right=team_data,on = 'Empl ID')
print(data_applied)
```

How do i improve the execution of the code the 2nd time around with out closing my session?

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: Ran your code in `jupyter notebook` and there was no delay either the first or second, or third, or ... check if other processes are not keeping your system busy.

Comment: @ChuckG Thanks. What i just noticed is. The delay is occurring the moment i add a new line of code. This is forcing me to kill the notebook. Never happened before. Thanks for Checking it.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code.

Comment: `dataapplied = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\metrics\TEST.xlsx',engine = 'xlsxwriter') data_applied.to_excel(dataapplied, index = False )
dataapplied.save()`. I added this for a sample and it stuck.

Comment: Did not even allow me to select the file

Comment: Try changing the environment you run your code from. If that does not help, I can't really help any further.